# Render React component based on user input

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jsx

The first (parent) div is underlined and shows: "This JSX tag's 'children' prop expects a single child of type 'ReactNode', but multiple children were provided.ts(2746)".

```js
import A from './components/A'
import B from './components/B'
import C from './components/C'

type Component = {
  name: String,
  component: JSX.Element  // is this the right type?
};

const [components, setComponents] = useState<Component[]>([]);
const [userInput, setUserInput] = useState<string>("");
const data = [
        { name: "a", component: <A/> },
        { name: "b", component: <B/> },
        { name: "c", component: <C/> },
    ];

function getComponent(e: FormEvent) {
        e.preventDefault();
        let c = data.filter((c) => c.name === userInput)[0];
        setComponents((prev) => [...prev, c]);
}

return (
  <div>
    <form onSubmit={(e) => getComponent(e)}>
        <input
            type="text"
            value={userInput}
            onChange={(e) => setUserInput(e.target.value)}
        />
    </form>
    <h1>Here are all components rendered</h1>
    // HERE'S THE PROBLEM  --------------------------
    {
      components.map(c => {
        c.component
      })
    }
   // IT DOESN'T WORK  ---------------------------------
 </div>
);
```

I don't get why this happens, since every component returns JSX. What am I missing? How can I make it work?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's because of an unexpected bracket.

```
{
  components.map(c => {
    c.component
  }
}
```

Plus, I don't think c.component is returned here...
You should remove the bracket inside the map function.

```
{components.map((c) => c.component)}
```